# Pycharm warning: Expected type 'collections.Iterable', got 'object' instead

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

In this program, I tried to use and compute a 2-dimensional matrix in Numpy, but while I was trying`.flatten()` to flatten the 2-d matrix into a 1-d list, something went wrong. Since the matrix after computing will be filled with 0 and 1, I used the`.join()` to convert the whole list into a binary type and got it wrong`for num in to_list`, which gave me the warning message: `Expected type 'collections.Iterable', got 'object' instead`.

Through the hint produced by Pycharm, it seems like `.tolist()` will return an `object` instead of a list in Python.

But it's pretty weird; didn't I use `.tolist()` beforehand? So, why would something like this happen?

[image]

```py
import numpy as np

def zero_matrix():
    matrix = np.zeros((8, 8), dtype=np.int32)
    # Compute something here
    return matrix.flatten()

def similarity(filename):
    to_binary = [0 for _ in range(len(filename))]

    # Build list
    for i in range(len(filename)):
        to_list = zero_matrix().astype(int).tolist()
        to_binary[i] = int("".join(str(num) for num in to_list), 2)
```

I have tried to break `zero_matrix().astype(int).tolist()` into two parts: `matrix = zero_matrix().astype(int)` and `to_list = matrix.tolist()` but it doesn't work as well.

Comment: Maybe the `tolist()` method just has bad type hints? Does the code run correctly, or do you get some sort of TypeError or other exception when you run it?

Comment: `.tolist()` doesn't *always* return an iterable: if `a` is a 0D array, then `a.tolist()` is a scalar: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html. So it can't provide a type hint of `list` or `Iterable` or similar.  However, if you know the input to the function is a 2D array, then you can safely iterate over the result. It's always worth remembering that Python is fundamentally a dynamically typed language. Type hints are hints and not guarantees.

Comment: @larks Yes, it runs correctly without any kind of TypeError, and the result is as expected as well.

Comment: @slothrop So the problem here is `.tolist()` has two kinds of return value, and Pycharm can't distinguish between either of them?

Comment: Basically yes, though it's not a PyCharm issue. PyCharm is just using the type hints that the function provides - and it would be wrong for the function to hint that it always returns a `list` or `Iterable`, because it doesn't.